# How to update Down library DownView content and keep the style?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift. I am using Down to render markdown and add it to my view, https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Down

I can add a `DownView` to my view (use code below) but how can I update the content inside it?

````
let cardFrontStr = "Use chained optional to simplify code below,\n\n```\nvar display: UILabel?\nif let label = display {\n  if let text = label.text {\n    let x = text.hasValue\n    // ...\n  }\n}\n```"
let cardfrontView = try? DownView(frame: cardfront.bounds, markdownString: cardFrontStr)
cardfront.addSubview(cardfrontView!)
````

Since the DownView is extended from `WebView`, I can update the content and `loadHTMLString`; however, the DownView style is gone after I have done so.

```
    let down = Down(markdownString: "`test`")
    let newStr = try? down.toHTML()
    cardbackView?.loadHTMLString(newStr!, baseURL: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't found any method written there for this. But you can try below method to update it.

First declare `cardfrontView` out side of methods in your class this way:

```
var cardfrontView: DownView?
```

Now create `cardfrontView` this way:

````
let cardFrontStr = "Use chained optional to simplify code below,\n\n```\nvar display: UILabel?\nif let label = display {\n  if let text = label.text {\n    let x = text.hasValue\n    // ...\n  }\n}\n```"
cardfrontView = try? DownView(frame: self.view.bounds, markdownString: cardFrontStr)
self.view.addSubview(cardfrontView!)
````

Now when you want to update content you can do it this way:

````
cardfrontView?.removeFromSuperview()
let cardFrontStr = "Updated Use chained optional to simplify code below,\n\n```\nvar display: UILabel?\nif let label = display {\n  if let text = label.text {\n    let x = text.hasValue\n    // ...\n  }\n}\n```"
cardfrontView = try? DownView(frame: self.view.bounds, markdownString: cardFrontStr)
self.view.addSubview(cardfrontView!)
````

Hope this will help.

Comment: I was thinking do so, but it has to keep recreating `WebView` and I think that probably bad. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)